# How can I return the array element chosen and modified by MongoDB's find_and_modify()?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb

I am using **pymongo** to call **MongoDB 3.2** (running on **Azure Cosmos DB**).  My app needs to, in an **atomic step**,  search for an array element in a document and if found, modify 1-2 of its fields.

The code below **does** find and modify the first matching array element, but my app **also needs** to know which array element was matched/modified.  In the general use of the function I am writing, I cannot rely on the update information to find the array element after the update (i.e., sometimes only the **status** field is modified).

When I try to use **$ projection** in the fields parameter to specify that the matching array element be returned, only the _id field is returned.  My code:

```
fd = {'_id': 'job7569', 'active_runs.node_id': 'node0', 'active_runs.status': 'unstarted'}
ud = {'active_runs.$.run_name': 'run8100.1', 'active_runs.$.status': 'started'}

result = self.mongo.mongo_db["__jobs__"].find_and_modify(fd, update={"$set": ud}, fields={"active_runs.$": 1}, new=True)
```

The result: `{'_id': 'job7569'}`

I expected: `{'_id': 'job7569', 'active_runs': [{'node_id': 'node0', 'run_index': 0, 'run_name': 'run8100.1', 'status': 'started'}]}`

Comment: What version of PyMongo?

Comment: pymongo==3.10.1